# How can I use an SLN file with MSBuild programmatically from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, microsoft.build

I am trying to create a custom MSBuild script in C#, using the newer `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` API.  The problem I have is that this newer API does not support `.sln` files.  The older deprecated `Microsoft.Build.Engine` API does support `.sln` files, but I'd like to use the newer one because 1) it's not deprecated and 2) there seems to be more online documentation and usage to reference.  I've seen that MSBuild can create a `.metaproj` file when is successfully compiles a solution, when this assignment is made in CMD: `set MSBuildEmitSolution=1`.  I need the `.metaproj` file to be able to compile the solution in the first place.  Is there anything in the API for converting `.sln` to `.metaproj`? Is there any library out there for parsing `.sln` files?

Comment: Do you mean the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` API does support .sln files? If not, you can use API `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` to programmatically build sln file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511380/how-do-i-build-a-solution-programmatically-in-c. Besides, The .NET 4.0 version of the Microsoft.Build assembly contains a SolutionParser class in the Microsoft.Build.Construction namespace that parses Visual Studio solution files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/parsing-visual-studio-solution-files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out after more searching.  Finding good examples online is a little difficult because of the two different versions of the MSBuild API, and the popularity of just running MSBuild from the command line.

Here is the code that is now working for me, using the newer MSBuild API:

```
var pc = new ProjectCollection();

var parameters = new BuildParameters(pc)
{
    Loggers = new[] { _logger } //Instance of ILogger instantiated earlier
};

var request = new BuildRequestData(
    projectFullPath: pathToMySlnFile, //Solution file path
    globalProperties: myPropertyDictionary,
    toolsVersion: null,
    targetsToBuild: myTargetsArray,
    hostServices: null,
    flags: BuildRequestDataFlags.ProvideProjectStateAfterBuild);

var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parameters, request);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Actually, I am now seeing some very strange behavior, and I was seeing part of this before which is why I confirmed your solution and then unconfirmed it once.  If I run in the debugger with this path added as a property, it works, but it will fail to find the correct targets file when not in the debugger.  If I remove the path property the opposite is true.  When it fails with the path added outside of the debugger, it is looking in the specified directory for v14.  The Microsoft.Build packages do not have a v15 yet. Maybe this is part of it

Comment: This didn't work for me. This did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349500/3286975 (NOTE: the BuildEngine API is deprecated).